# Setting up a MouseListener

Tags: java

I'm coding a Blackjack program, and I am trying to setup a `MouseListener` for a label I have, but I am unable to get it to work. I have looked at many websites and other people's questions on StackOverflow, but none of them were helpful, or I was not able to put them into use properly. Why does this code not work:

```
JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\rawlc\\Pictures\\kings1.jpg"));
lbl1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (mode == false)
            if (bet > 0)
                bet -= 1;
        else
            if (bank > bet + 1)
                bet += 1;
        lblBet1.setText(String.valueOf(bet));
        if (bet == 0)
            btnMode.setEnabled(false);
        else
            btnMode.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
});
c.gridy = 2;
c.gridx = 0;
panel4.add(lbl1, c);
```

Comment: Can you narrow the problem to something precise, what is the behavior expected vs encountered, is there an error message ?

Comment: You want a mouse listener for your JLabel. Got it. Why do you want a mouse listener?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

When you use `MouseListener` method `mouseEntered` will call before call `mouseClicked`. Try use `MouseAdapter` sample:

```
       label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(".mouseClicked()");
            }

        });
```

I hope it can help you! Please feedback if it helpful.

Comment: @ConnorRawlings My answer can't help you?